# Where to get list of UI element names on which permissions can be applied via GetUIElementInfo?

Tags: kentico, kentico-api

I need to apply UI personalization permissions to roles and found this article: https://docs.kentico.com/api11/configuration/roles#Roles-AssigningaUIelementtoarole

Where can I find a list of possible values of the `GetUIElementInfo(string, string)` overload?

**EDIT**:
For instance I would like to find all matching resources and elements for this graphic:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find that info in DB. Although it's not very intuitive, but it can be used as good starting point for further investigation.

```
SELECT res.[ResourceName], ui.[ElementName], ui.[ElementDescription] 
FROM [dbo].[CMS_Resource] AS res      
JOIN [dbo].[CMS_UIElement] AS ui ON ui.[ElementResourceID] = res.[ResourceID]
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I see CMS.Content EditForm in the SQL result, but I need CMS > Administration > Content Management > Pages > Edit > Page

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I found was inspecting the desired checkbox in the browser and noting the id of the element in HTML. It matches the `[CMS_UIElement].[ElementResourceID]` in SQL database.

[image: screenshot of inspect checbox in firefox]

Just sharing a list of elements I got from accepted answer. Just in case anyone needs to use it.

[image: Kentico 11.0.26 Selective UI Permissions List]